# google chart api material date month

Tags: google-visualization

I have a google bar chart with multiple series and a date hAxis.

My problem is that i want to show months only, but i get the label multiple times.
Here's an example

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['bar'], 'language': 'de'});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

  var chart;
  var chartDiv = document.getElementById('test');

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable('{"cols":[{"type":"date","pattern":""},{"type":"number"},{"type":"number"},{"type":"number"},{"type":"number"},{"type":"number"},{"type":"number"},{"type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,2,1)"},{"v":2030,"f":"2030 km"},{"v":2098,"f":"2098 km"},{"v":1352,"f":"1352 km"},{"v":4412,"f":"4412 km"},{"v":132,"f":"132 km"},{"v":2435,"f":"2435 km"},{"v":3952,"f":"3952 km"}]},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2016,3,1)"},{"v":3177,"f":"3177 km"},{"v":2901,"f":"2901 km"},{"v":2491,"f":"2491 km"},{"v":1480,"f":"1480 km"},{"v":2272,"f":"2272 km"},{"v":400,"f":"400 km"},{"v":1096,"f":"1096 km"}]}]}');

  var options = {
    legend: { position: 'none' },
    hAxis: {
      type: 'category',
      format: 'MMMM'
    }
  };

  chart = new google.charts.Bar(chartDiv);
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1Lusd06n/3/

If i shrink the width of the fiddle, the month names are grouped and displayed once but this does not happen if there is more space.

Comment: With a CoreChart, you can set your own hAxis.ticks -- but doesn't appear to work with Material chrts

Comment: the fiddle looks correct to me.

Comment: @WhoAmI please increase the width of the right chart container and rerun the fiddle. Than the problem will be clear